# How to change a QPushButton's Icon String based on QTranslator

Tags: qt, translation, qpushbutton, qaction, qtranslator

I have an application with buttons that have icons set for the various click states, no actual QPushButton text is set or displayed; it is all contained in the icon.

These icon files include text that requires translation, and have already been generated for each language and state. I am looking for a way to use the QTranslator or QAction class to automatically select which localized version of the button to use based on the selected main language.

For example:

```
BTN_Media_Browse->setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap(tr(":/Images/BTN_Media_Browse_Unpressed.png"))));
```

I have followed the instructions on the [QT Wiki: Multi Language Application](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_multi_language_application) but the buttons do not show up in the generated translation (.ts) files. Having a switch case for each instance of its use based on the language is not ideal.

Comment: Do you want to translate the entire text or just a part of it?

Comment: I want to translate the location text. For example: `tr(":/Images/BTN_Media_Browse_Unpressed.png")` becomes `":/Images/BTN_Media_Browse_Unpressed_en.png"` or `":/Images/BTN_Media_Browse_Unpressed_de.png"`
Edited for clarity.

Comment: You could share your test code through github, drive, dropbox or similar.

Comment: You can use .qrc file. See **The Qt Resource System** topic. For example: `<qresource>
      <file>cut.jpg</file>
  </qresource>
  <qresource lang="fr">
      <file alias="cut.jpg">cut_fr.jpg</file>
  </qresource>`

Comment: This worked wonderfully. Please provide this as an answer so I can accept it. It might be worth adding a bit more clarification or a link for others who were confused like me.

Answer (score 0):

To use different icons depending on the user's locale, you can add `qresource` section with `lang` attribute in your .qrc file.

For example:

```
<qresource>
    ...
    <file alias="Images/BTN_Media_Browse_Unpressed.png">Images/BTN_Media_Browse_Unpressed_en.png</file>
    ...
</qresource>
<qresource lang="de">
    ...
    <file alias="Images/BTN_Media_Browse_Unpressed.png">Images/BTN_Media_Browse_Unpressed_de.png</file>
    ...
</qresource>
```

Then you can use it with code like this:

```
BTN_Media_Browse->setIcon(QIcon(":/Images/BTN_Media_Browse_Unpressed.png"));
```